# What tag should I use to ask questions about the P programming language?

Tags: discussion, tags

Microsoft recently open-sourced their [P programming language](https://github.com/p-org/P).  I don't see a [p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p) or [p-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p-lang) tag.  If I wanted to ask a question about the language, what tag should I use?  If a new tag were to be created, what should it be?

Comment: IMO you should just create a new tag [p].

Comment: @Gothdo not to be confused with [P′′](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2)

Comment: how about P-lang-MS or something similar

Comment: Considering we also have something like `[r]` and `[f#]` and `[c]` I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: The tag was just used incorrectly [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141785/analytics-script-and-webtrends-in-the-same-website).

Comment: @NobodyNada well that was quick...

Comment: @NobodyNada that tag doesn't even make any sense in the context of that question...  It's not about HTML or anything with "p"

Comment: This just happened again with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40261628/2415822).  I don't know what's wrong with people...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) is just done as a single character tag. I don't think there's any reason it should be different for [p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p).

Comment: I fear that creating a tag named [tag:p] will lead to legitimate questions about the P Programming Language being drowned out by incorrectly tagged HTML questions somehow involving the `<p>` element.

Comment: @JörgWMittag `<q>` is a HTML element as well, albeit likely not as popular as `<p>`, but [q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/q) is a single-letter tag on SO as well.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: And it seems to be used for at least three unrelated things: the **Q** Programming Language, the **Q**.js ECMAScript library, and as a meta-tag for **Q**uestions(?!?)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: you mean a meta-Q as in [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39671300/2564301)?

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's where editing comes in. People interested in the P language will edit HTML questions out.

Comment: I've asked [my first P language question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40138155/2415822) using the single-letter tag.  I will be monitoring the tag to see what other questions it is added to.